# How to add stop words from Tfidvectorizer?

Tags: python-3.x, stop-words

I am trying to add stop words into my stop_word list, however, the code I am using doesn't seem to be working:

Creating stop words list:

`stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')`

`CustomListofWordstoExclude = ['rt']`

`stopwords1 = stopwords.extend(CustomListofWordstoExclude)`

Here I am converting the text to a dtm (document term matrix) with tfidf weighting:

`vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = 'english', min_df=150, token_pattern=u'\\b[^\\d\\W]+\\b')`

`dtm = vect.fit_transform(df['tweets'])`

`dtm.shape`

But when I do this, I get this error:

FutureWarning: Pass input=None as keyword args. From version 0.25 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error
warnings.warn("Pass {} as keyword args. From version 0.25 "

What does this mean? Is there an easier way to add stopwords?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the warning.  However, note that a warning such as this does not mean that your code did not run as intended.  It means that in future releases of the package it may not work as intended.  So if you try the same thing next year with updated packages, it may not work.

With respect to your question about using stop words, there are two changes that need to be made for your code to work as you expect.

1. `list.extend()` extends the list in-place, but it doesn't return the list.  To see this you can do `type(stopwords1)` which gives `NoneType`.  To define a new variable and add the custom words list to `stopwords` in one line, you could just use the built-in `+` operator functionality for lists:

```
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
CustomListofWordstoExclude = ['rt']
stopwords1 = stopwords + CustomListofWordstoExclude
```

2. To actually use `stopwords1` as your new stopwords list when performing the TF-IDF vectorization, you need to pass `stop_words=stopwords1`:

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords1,  # Passed stopwords1 here
                       min_df=150, 
                       token_pattern=u'\\b[^\\d\\W]+\\b')
dtm = vect.fit_transform(df['tweets'])
dtm.shape
```